# aws ssm proxycommand for interactive session

Tags: openssh, aws-ssm

Goal: Log into ec2 instance via SSM to an ssh terminal using a proxycommand

I can log into my instance fine using 'aws ssm start-session --target intance-id'.  However to make life simpler, I want to be able to have a proxycommand in my .ssh/config that will allow me to ssh into the instance with a shorter command such as 'ssh i-awsguid' and the proxycommand will fill in the rest.

However, when I do this, I get a session that hangs without ever seeing the prompt of the remote machine, and on control-c, I see the json output of the aws action.

```
$ ssh i-076efab920fd7a5e2 -v
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 49: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 70: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/user/.ssh/config line 86: Applying options for i-*
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec aws ssm start-session --target i-076efab920fd7a5e2
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: 
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: Starting session with SessionId: user@email.com-0a7ca620b0b70ba7c
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: This session is encrypted using AWS KMS.
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: echo Connected to $(hostname)
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: $ Connected to ip-10-147-34-181
^C

Command '['session-manager-plugin', '{"SessionId": "user@email.com-0a7ca620b0b70ba7c", "TokenValue": "scrubbed", "StreamUrl": "wss://ssmmessages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/data-channel/user@email.com-0a7ca620b0b70ba7c?role=publish_subscribe", "ResponseMetadata": {"RequestId": "cd75db36-3cc0-415f-b849-b5995e1701ec", "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": {"server": "Server", "date": "Wed, 07 Apr 2021 17:49:22 GMT", "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1", "content-length": "678", "connection": "keep-alive", "x-amzn-requestid": "cd75db36-3cc0-415f-b849-b5995e1701ec"}, "RetryAttempts": 0}}', 'us-east-1', 'StartSession', '', '{"Target": "i-076efab920fd7a5e2"}', 'https://ssm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com']' died with <Signals.SIGPIPE: 13>.
```

example calling same instance directly from shell.

```
$ aws ssm start-session --target i-076efab920fd7a5e2

Starting session with SessionId: user@email.com-0bcfc5bf3d8325cb1
This session is encrypted using AWS KMS.
echo Connected to $(hostname)
$ Connected to ip-10-147-34-181
$ whoami
ssm-user
$ exit


Exiting session with sessionId: user@email.com-0bcfc5bf3d8325cb1.
```

relevant part of .ssh/config

```
# SSH over Session Manager
host i-*
    ProxyCommand aws ssm start-session --target %h
```

Comment: I think I've got a similar problem @gregs did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your proxy command is the `aws` cli. The JSON output does say that the command succeeded. But you haven't asked for a shell, you just asked for executing an `aws` command.

According to the [AWS docs on SSH sessions through SSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-enable-ssh-connections.html), you pass the `aws` command as an argument to a shell:

- `sh` for MacOS and Linux (I presume `sh` exists in MacOS as in Linux)
- Windows PowerShell for Windows (`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`), although I guess that it would work with the command line

Also, I only got it working by

- having a SSH private key on my PC
- having my SSH public key in my VM's `~/.ssh/config/authorized_keys`
- specifying my username in my VM in the `host` config
- specifying an AWS document in the proxy command, `AWS-StartSSHSession`
- passing the port number variable `%p`

Having to use my username and a SSH key may be because my IAM account does not have the right permissions, so it's not a perfect solution. (But I don't control those permissions in my workplace.)

Judging by the debug info, you're on a Mac, right? So your `.ssh/config` host should be:

```
# SSH over Session Manager
# you may need the region as a parameter to aws, e.g. --region us-east-1
host i-*
    User YourUsername
    ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
```

In my case, in PowerShell, since I have to use many AWS accounts, I specify the right AWS profile in the proxy command:

```
# SSH over Session Manager on a specific hostname
# using PowerShell and a specific AWS profile
Host myVM
  HostName i-xxxxxxxxxxx
  User myusername
  ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "aws ssm start-session --profile myAwsProfile --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters portNumber=%p"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The point of connecting via aws ssm is not to use SSH, thereby not using the SSH port (because it might be blocked and only availble through bastion) and not using public / private key. Yet, you mention this in your answer - doesn't make sense, and your solution doesn't work

Comment: The stated goal is to "Log into ec2 instance via SSM to an ssh terminal using a proxycommand". My understanding is that the point of ProxyCommand is to delegate the connection to another process than SSH. And that is what the original poster is trying to do, with the "ssh" command.

And that's exactly what I am forced to do at work, because AWS SSO is required and SSH ports are blocked. I use the ssh config above to log in to EC2 instances that do not expose IPs outside their VPC. Exactly like the OP is asking. Yet ssh is still required for authentication to the EC2 instance.